# Assigning roles to the user

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to get my bot to do role assignments to users via reactions, but for the purpose of getting it to work, I wrote the code inside a test command to first make sure it works. This is what I came up with:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True) 
async def Role(ctx):
    user = ctx.author #get user object from context
    role = get(user.guild.roles, name="testrole") #get role object by name from the get function from discord utils.
    await client.add_roles(user, role) #assign role using the add_roles coroutine by using the user and role variables as arguments
```

The console outputs:

> AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

I get this means that the client 'bot' doesn't understand what add_roles is, am I missing some kind of reference or argument?

Comment: It is done on a user not the client/bot. Try `await user.add_roles(role)`

Comment: I see. So you have to do the coroutine on the user object. But now there is a different problem, it throws a 404 error exception, which means that it can't find the role. I think this line: ```role = get(user.guild.roles, name="testrole")``` because I suspect its not getting the object correctly.